# Trigger html5 input datalist dropdown to show up

Tags: javascript, html

In an HTML5 `<input>` element with pre-defined values in a `<datalist>`, when user either enters a matching value or hits the <kbd>down</kbd> key, the dropdown list shows up.

Is there a way to trigger this dropdown list to show up? I might change the `datalist` dynamically in Angular, and so would like to have a way to trigger the showing up of this list.

```html
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can:

```js
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";

keyboardEvent[initMethod](
  "keyup", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
  true, // bubbles
  true, // cancelable
  window, // viewArg: should be window
  false, // ctrlKeyArg
  false, // altKeyArg
  false, // shiftKeyArg
  false, // metaKeyArg
  40, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
  0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
document.getElementById("test").focus();
document.getElementById("test").dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

```html
<input id="test" list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Using `dispatchEvent` and `createEvent`. Supported by IE9+, Chrome and FF.

Comment: it's not working on the touch keyboard, why? should I send a keypress trigger? I want open list when clicking touch keyboard keys

Comment: I ended up doing this (alas a jquery fix): `$(element).trigger(jQuery.Event('keyup', { keycode: 40 }));`