# Html datalist open list onclick show list function

Tags: javascript, html, datalist

Hello I'm searching for a solution that open the option list of a datalist by click on a button.

```
<input value="" list="default">
<i class="fa fa-caret-down innerinput" onclick="showList();"></i>

<datalist id="default">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Please refer to this fiddle link:
    http://jsfiddle.net/3zpco1xe/1/

[input][icon]
-> icon show datalist options
(function if you click into the input field)

Any solution for this?

Comment: The general idea to achieve this is we can programmtically(manually) trigger the **HTML focus event** or **key up event** on that input element that associates with that datalist. Here is a robust solution. [Trigger html5 input datalist dropdown to show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995653/trigger-html5-input-datalist-dropdown-to-show-up)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Please Click on the icon to show the list. Hope this will help you.

```js
function showList(v)
{  
    document.getElementById('dd').value='';
}
```

```html
<input value="" list="default" id="dd" onclick="showList(this.value)">


<datalist id="default">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
function showList(){
    cat = document.getElementById("default");
    cat.style.display = "block";
}
```