# How can I trigger HTML5 datalist dropdown on via tab or why I shouldn't?

Tags: html, usability, html-datalist

```html
<input type="text">

<datalist id="popular-descriptions">
  <option value="Datalist option A"></option>
  <option value="Datalist option B"></option>
</datalist>
    
<input type="text" list="popular-descriptions">
```

HTML5 datalist dropdown is not triggered when I focus input by pressing tab from previous input. How can I fix that?

Here's how input with datalist looks when I **focus it by clicking on it**
[image]

And here's how it looks when I **'tab' into it from previous input**:
[image]

Firefox has gone even further and reveals datalist dropdown only when you click on the input a second time

How can I trigger the dropdown in case user focused the input using tab key or up/down arrow on iOS keyboard?

Or is there a reason why it's not a default behaviour?

Comment: You can fake it on keyup like [some folks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995653/trigger-html5-input-datalist-dropdown-to-show-up?rq=1) opt for but datalist has low [a11y compliance](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/html/datalist_element) and can have [browser nuances](https://caniuse.com/#search=datalist) so personally I usually just use custom dropdowns instead.

Comment: @ChrisW. Oh snap. I assumed that datalist would have a better a11y compliance than all those half-baked js+css autocomplete dropdowns because it's a part of HTML specification and browser developers care more about a11y than your regular 'run of the mill' web devs.

Comment: Haha dude I just excited when someone actually knows what A11Y / WCAG / W3C etc actually is! More often than not a "full stack dev" knows html/css and actual proper presentation layer code compliance up to the standards of a hobbyist who knows just enough to throw something out there but it doesn't fly in enterprise apps. So bravo! :D - PS, I ended up just making my own, completely agree most of the examples out there aren't too stellar for nitpickers lol.